# Generics problems encountered by Kotlin and GSON

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I try to write a network request function，Its role is to analyze the general format and provide data content to callbacks.

This is my defined class:

```
data class Response<T>(
    val code: Int = 0,
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    var data: ArrayList<T>,
    val message: String = "")
```

in this class 'code' and 'message' is fixed，'data' has different types

Select one of data:

```
data class TestData(
    @SerializedName("create_by")
    val createBy: String = "",
    @SerializedName("create_time")
    val createTime: String = "",
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String = "",
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String = "")
```

There is my network request function:

```
fun <T> post(callBack: (ArrayList<T>) -> Unit) {
    ...
     override fun onSuccess(response:Response<String>) {
          val result = gson.fromJson<Response<T>>(response.body().reader(),Response::class.java)
          when{
              result.code==200-> callBack.invoke(result.data)
          }
     }
    ...
}
```

Use it at Activity:

```
Request.addr(Constants.GET_TEST)
       .post<TestData> {
            tv.text = it[0].name
        }
```

When i use Gson parse the server returns data,and want use JavaBean ,Logcat throw this Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.example.network.response.TestData

i tried to use TypeToken to solve this problem ，but it also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cause, because the parser can't fetch the real type T at runtime.
This extension works for me

*inline fun  Gson.fromJson(json: String) =
        this.fromJson(json, object: TypeToken() {}.type)!!*

Then you need modify  as  in you methods, as IDE recommend you.